# Getting the context from a different assembly

Tags: c#, unity-container, signalr

In my project I have different assemblies.

The SignalR hub (and client MVC4 files) live in the `Website` project.

My hub looks like this:

```
public class PredictHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IChat _chat;

    public PredictHub(IChat chat)
    {
        _chat = chat;
    }

    public void Chat(String message)
    {
        _chat.AddMessage(message);
    }
}
```

In my second assembly `Business` the `IChat.cs` and `Chat.cs` live:

```
public class Chat : IChat
{
    public void AddMessage(String message)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
    }
}
```

But because `Chat.cs` is in the `Business` assembly the `ChatHub` directive is not known because it's not referenced.

How could this be solved?

Comment: The simplest way would be to move `Chat.cs` in your `Website` project.

Comment: Yes ofcourse :) But I have all my business logic in that assembly, moving everything would create tons of work..

Comment: Use something like `IChatHub` i.e. the interface - that's usually the way to resolve this kind of stuff. Have a base library which holds 'interfaces' - you ref that from both places - and you can have it all. You just 'implement' the interface in your web-site (or better even some other lib).

Comment: if it helped let us know, to add an answer or close it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get the context when SignalR and the Chat class are in the same process.

Comment: In essential this is the only correct answer. I have fiddeled around alot with nasty proxies etc, but the easiest solution is not to move the business logic to the hub but the hub to the business logic. I moved all my hubs out of the `Website` assembly into the `Business` assembly.